# Single page design - loading new content on link click

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm working on a django webpage using single page design approach. Generally what I'm trying to achieve is to have some new content being loaded (picture gallery) to my main webpage after clicking certain links.

What I have already achieved is that the new content is being loaded on a link click but unfortunately it seems like the whole page is being reloaded and not rendered correctly. My current implementation is based on having main `index.html` template and extension template, both using `{% block content %}` relation.

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all().order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'categories': categories})

def gallery(request, id):
   category = Category.objects.get(id=id)
   return render(request, 'gallery.html', {'category': category})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('view_gallery/<int:id>/', views.gallery, name='view_gallery')
]
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        {% for category in categories%}
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'view_gallery' category.id %}">{{ category.name }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}  
    </ul>
</div> 
<div>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

**gallery.html**

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <p>{{ category.name }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

I hope I have explained clearly what I'm trying to achieve. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests and page changes in single page sites work quite differently than those for normal web pages. Single page sites use JavaScript to change the page content rather than requesting a new page from the server. Single page sites can request content from the server, but generally that content is just data while the structure (HTML) of the page is decided by the client in JavaScript. The only time a full HTML page is sent by the server is on the initial request, which should be responded to with `index.html`.

In your example, you could have this work by adding a script that requests content from the server and modifies the DOM when a link is clicked.

For example:

```js
const a1 = document.querySelector("a.link1");
const a2 = document.querySelector("a.link2");

a1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  setContent("<p>Content from link 1</p>")
});

a2.addEventListener("click", () => {
  setContent("<p>Content from link 2</p>")
});


function setContent(content) {
   const contentDiv = document.querySelector("div.content");
   contentDiv.innerHTML = content;
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}

a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Page</h1>

<a class="link1">link 1</a>
<a class="link2">link 2</a>

<div class="content">
</div>
```

And the click event callbacks could request content from your server instead of having the content hard-coded as in this example. Note that then the server should respond with just a snippet of HTML rather than an entire new page.

For example, you could use the following function to get content for the `div.content` element:

```
function fetchData() {
    const response = fetch("/gallery");
    return response;
}
```

If you're new to single page sites, you might checkout a framework like [React](https://reactjs.org/), [Vue](https://vuejs.org/), or [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) to get started and gain a better understanding or even use for this project.